# React: Preview content while typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple list where I'm adding media content.
I'm using [Embed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-embed) to display the media contents.

When I want to enter a media link suck as Youtube/twitter .., I want to be able to preview it **after pasting it** and **before clicking on Add**.

I tried to add an `onChange` but didn't work. How to do so ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-greider-seycx?file=/src/App.js:0-1201

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Embed from "react-embed";

export default () => {
  const reactList = [
    {
      id: "2",
      title: "Twitter",
      media: "https://twitter.com/Betclic/status/1382074820628783116?s=20"
    }
  ];

  const [links, setLinks] = useState(reactList);
  const [media, setMedia] = React.useState("");

  function handleChange(event) {
    setMedia(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleAdd() {
    const newList = links.concat({ media });
    setLinks(newList);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={media} onChange={handleChange} />

        <div
          style={{ height: "250px", width: "500px", border: "3px solid black" }}
        >
          Preview
          <Embed url={media} onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>

        <button type="button" onClick={handleAdd}>
          Add
        </button>
      </div>

      <ul>
        <div style={{ width: "50vh" }}>
          {links.reverse().map((url, indexurl) => (
            <li key={url.id}>
              <div>{url.title}</div>
              <Embed url={url.media} />
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I think I have to set an automatic refresh for the component, because when I set the link in a modal, after closing and reopening the modal, it works. What do you think?

Comment: You can just replace `<Embed url={media} onChange={handleChange} />` with `{media && <Embed url={media} />}`
I would validate it's a valid url in the handleChange though

Comment: @Narkast Thank you very much it's working ! Please can you explain what the line you suggested does ? I'm still learning React.

Comment: Sure. When you use `{some_code}` in JSX, you're telling React to run that piece of code and render whatever it returns. In this case, `{media && <Embed url={media} />}` returns either an empty string when media is falsy (the initial value of media) or it returns an `Embed` when media is truthy (basically, after you set it). You can learn more about falsy and truthy in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: @Narkast Thank you so much for the explanation. Your provided links are what I was looking for, I hope to understand more. Thanks again.